# What to do about compilation errors if ignoring them makes the app run fine?

Tags: web-development, type-systems, static-typing, typescript, angular

Updating the  libraries in my Angular 8/Electron app produced compilations errors eg, in Electron's `menu.ts` file, Also, a few of the  project external libraries contain  `@ts-ignore` lines, suppressing compilation errors. Some of these have comments "safe to ignore because..." while others don't.

As I couldn't solve the new compilation errors, I've also used `@ts.ignore`. The app compiles and runs fine.

If I could eliminate compilation errors or prove them harmless, I would.  But what to do about the other post-update errors in my code, as well as `@ts-ignored` errors in libraries? Would ignoring them bring trouble in  the future, despite the app seemingly working in the present?

Comment: I can only guess you mean warnings. You don't suppress compilation errors. If you run anyway you're running old code that doesn't have your changes.

Comment: That's a good point about the distinction about warnings vs. errors.  Perhaps I should edit the post? However, in my case removing `@ts.ignore` from `menu.ts` makes the app fail to compile. (Or maybe it's something to do with the "error severity level" in my IDE? Although it was not changed since before the update.)

Comment: It really depends on the error itself.  Ignoring compile errors may be latent bugs waiting for the right conditions to surface.  However, if you can be sure those conditions can't surface, it might be safe to ignore the error.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with TS script as I aught to be though.  My guess is your error may be related to additional safeties TS enforces that JavaScript does not need.  Since it compiles down to JavaScript, the underlying language may be able to handle it OK.